# ASP.NET core 2.2: what is the expected behaviour of ChallengeResult when there are multiple authentication schemes configured?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core, authorization

We are trying to understand what is the expected handling of a ChallengeResult when there are multiple authentication schemes registered.

We need to handle such a scenario because we have an ASP.NET core 2.2 app exposing some action methods (we use the MVC middleware) that must be used by an angularjs SPA which relies on cookies authentication and some third parties applications which use an authentication mechanism based on the Authorization HTTP request header. Please notice that **the involved action methods are the same for both the users**, this means that each one of them must allow authentication using both the cookie and the custom scheme based on  Authorization HTTP request header. We know that probably this is not an optimal design but we cannot  modify the overall architecture.

[This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=aspnetcore2x) seems to confirm that what we would like to achieve is entirely possible using ASP.NET core 2.2. Unfortunately, the cookie authentication used by the UI app and the custom authentication used by the third parties must behave differently in case of an authentication challenge and their expected behaviors are not compatible with each other: the UI app should redirect the user to a login form, while a thir party application expects a raw 401 status code response. The documentation linked above does not offer a clear explanation of the ChallengeResult handling, so we decided to experiment with a test application.

We created two fake authentication handlers:

```
public class FooAuthenticationHandler : IAuthenticationHandler
  {
    private HttpContext _context;

    public Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateAsync()
    {
      return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Foo failed"));
    }

    public Task ChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
      _context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task ForbidAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
    {
      _context = context;
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
  }
```

```
public class BarAuthenticationHandler : IAuthenticationHandler
  {
    private HttpContext _context;

    public Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateAsync()
    {
      return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Bar failed"));
    }

    public Task ChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
      _context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task ForbidAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
    {
      _context = context;
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
  }
```

We registered the authentication schemas inside ConfigureServices method as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services
        .AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

      services.AddAuthentication(options => 
      {
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Bar";
        options.AddScheme<FooAuthenticationHandler>("Foo", "Foo scheme");
        options.AddScheme<BarAuthenticationHandler>("Bar", "Bar scheme");
      });
    }
```

This is our middleware pipeline:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }
      else
      {
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
      }

      app.UseHttpsRedirection();

      app.UseAuthentication();

      app.UseMvc();
    }
```

and finally we created a controller with an action method requiring authentication:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
  [ApiController]
  public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
  {
    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Foo,Bar")]
    public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
    {
      return "value";
    }
  }
```

We noticed that:

- both the `FooAuthenticationHandler` and `BarAuthenticationHandler` are called to handle the ChallengeResult
- the order is `FooAuthenticationHandler` before `BarAuthenticationHandler` and depends on the `Authorize` attribute (if you swap the authentication schemes inside the `Authorize` attribute then `BarAuthenticationHandler` is called first)
- the caller gets a raw 500 status code response, but this only depends on the order in which the authorization handlers are called
- the call to `options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Bar";` matters **if and only if** inside the `[Authorize]` attribute the property `AuthenticationSchemes` is **not** set. If you do so, only the  `BarAuthenticationHandler` is called and `FooAuthenticationHandler` never gets a chance to authenticate the request or handle an authentication challenge.

So, the question basically is: when you have such a scenario, how are you expected to handle the possible "incompatibility" of different authentication schemes regarding ChallengeResult handling since they get **both** called ?

In our opinion is fine that both have a chance to authenticate the request, but we would like to know if it is possible to decide which one should handle the authentication challenge.

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not specify the schemes on the Authorize attribute.
Instead, specify one scheme as the default, and setup a forward selector.

The implementation of the selector depends on your case, but usually you can somehow figure out which scheme was used in a request.

For example, here is an example from the setup of an OpenID Connect scheme.

```
o.ForwardDefaultSelector = ctx =>
{
    // If the current request is for this app's API
    // use JWT Bearer authentication instead
    return ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api")
        ? JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
        : null;
};
```

So what it does is forward challenges (and well, everything) to the JWT handler if the route starts with /api.
You can do any kind of checks there, headers etc.

So in this case OpenID Connect and Cookies are setup as defaults for everything, but if a call is received that is going to the API, use JWT authentication.

The example here forwards all the "actions" you can do with authentication (challenge, forbid etc.).
You can also setup forward selectors for just challenges etc.

Comment: doing as you suggest is it possible to give **both** the authentication handlers a chance of performing authentication, but force (based on a proper condition) the handling of authentication challenge to only **one** of them ?  If it's possible, we should select the proper handler for authentication challenge based on the type of call we receive (if angularjs then cookie else custom handler). Is it correct ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the 2 schemes you want to support?

Comment: The app is currently written in .NET 4.7.1 and it is an ASP.NET MVC 5 application. We want to migrate it to ASP.NET core 2.2. All the authentication mechanism is custom, we basically have a custom identity server implementation. The top level plan for the migration is using the cookie scheme for the angularjs client app, and a custom scheme based on the Authorize HTTP request header for the third parties applications (server to server calls on client to server calls performed by projects using our infrastructure).

Comment: Currently we have some ASP.NET web api 2 controllers which are used by **both** the angularjs client and the third parties integrators. The current (custom) authentication mechanism performs several attempts to authenticate the request, it basically checks for a cookie and for the Authorize header. If it finds either of them it sets an identity for the request User principal and the request is authenticated. We are trying to figure out how to port this implementation to ASP.NET core.

Comment: apart from our specific production scenario, I would like to understand how the authentication framework of ASP.NET core has been designed to handle these 
kind of scenarios with multiple authentication schemes configured having different behaviors in case of authentication challenge (I mean, what is the best practice ? what is the expected way of using the provided apis for authentication ?).